# Validate the conformance of an OpenSSL created certificate with FIPs standards

Tags: openssl, key-management, fips, common-criteria

Trying to test the conformance of the certificates inside our application, with the below requirement:

> The application shall [**selection**: invoke platform-provided
> functionality, implement functionality ] to generate asymmetric
> cryptographic keys in accordance with a specified cryptographic key
> generation algorithm
> **RSA schemes using cryptographic key sizes of 2048-bit or greater that meet the following: FIPS PUB 186-4, “Digital Signature Standard (DSS)”, Appendix B.3**

As regards the `key sizes of 2048-bit or greater`, The self-signed certificates have their keys generated with this `openssl` command:

```
openssl genrsa -sha256 -out server.key.pem 2048
```

I assume this satisfies the requirement. The output of the final certificate with the command `openssl x509 -noout -text certificate.crt` has also these proofs:

```
...
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
...
Subject Public Key Info:
    Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
        Public-Key: (2048 bit)
```

But as per conformance with "**[FIPS PUB 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf), Appendix B.3**", I couldn't verify it, as the referenced "**Appendix B.3**" comprises very technical and low-level specifications.

1. Are there any ready-to-use tools that do these validations on an inputted certificate?
2. How could I make a certificate which is conformant with `FIPS PUB 186-4, Appendix B.3` by passing correct parameters to `openssl` command?
3. What are the potential clues in the output of `openssl x509 -noout -text certificate.crt` that indicate a certificate is meeting the `FIPS PUB 186-4, Appendix B.3` requirements?

P.s: my OpenSSL is version 1.1.1 on Ubuntu. I saw something about `OpenSSL FIPS Object Module 2.0 and FIPS 186-4` but couldn't figure out is it included in the default OpenSSL package, Or it should be utilized along with the default OpenSSL.

Thanks

Comment: Note that FIPS mandates methods to generate the private key, not just results. So checking key size or even running probabilistic principality testing on p and q is not enough. Upstream openssl 1.1.1 is not FIPS certified, but Ubuntu has a FIPS certification for their openssl 1.1.1: https://ubuntu.com/blog/fips-certification-ubuntu-18-04-lts 
I don't know how to run the openssl 1.1.1 in ubuntu in FIPS-mode though.

Comment: @Z.T. Thanks, In regard to this phrase `FIPS mandates methods to generate the private key, not just results` ;  The auditor would check the requirements on the created certificates (keys) I assume. So How could they verify the conformity of the final output (the certificate, not its creation process) with Fips 186-4, Appendix B.3?

Comment: I suspect an auditor would just verify the thing that generated the keys is fips certified. Just by looking at the certificate and even the corresponding private key, there is no way to know how it was generated, except that some implementations definitely can't generate some valid values, so it's possible to say "this definitely wasn't generated by X", but you can't say "this definitely was generated by X".

Comment: One of the issues with cryptography is that unless you specifically test for the specific issue, something like a Debian weak key (CVE-2008-0166) or a ROCA weak key (CVE-2017-15361) would look perfectly fine and pass all the usual tests, despite being insecure. Looking at the result is not enough, that is why FIPS mandates a process that generates the keys, not some test of the result.

Comment: @Z.T. I see, Wasn't familiar with this aspect of FIPS requirements. Thank you